# Is there a way in python pandas to do "Text to Columns" by location (not by a delimiter) like in excel?

Tags: python, pandas, data-mining

I'm using Vote History data from the Secretary of State, however the .txt file they gave me is 7 million rows, where each row is a string with 27 characters. The first 3 characters are a code for the county. The next 8 characters are the registration ID, the next 8 characters are the date voted, etc. I can't do text to columns in excel because the file is too big. Is there a way to separate this file into columns in python pandas?

Example

Currently I have:

```
0010000413707312012026R

0010000413708212012027R

0010000413711062012029

0010004535307312012026D
```

I want to have columns:

```
001 00004137 07312012 026 R

001 00004137 08212012 027 R

001 00004137 11062012 029

001 00045353 07312012 026 D
```

Where each space separates a new column. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html? You can take a string and turn it into two or more columns.

Comment: Yes, I initially thought about using the split function, but I believe there has to be some kind of delimiter separating the columns to use this, whereas my dataset has no delimiter. I'm relatively new to python so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:
I think you don't have issue reading form `txt` file,simplified case would be like here:

```
a=['0010000413707312012026R','0010000413708212012027R','0010000413711062012029','0010004535307312012026D']
area=[]
date=[]
e1=[]
e2=[]
e3=[]
#001 00004137 07312012 026 R
for i in range (0,len(a)):
    area.append(a[i][0:3])
    date.append(a[i][3:11])
    e1.append(a[i][11:19])
    e2.append(a[i][19:22])
    e3.append(a[i][22:23])


all_list = pd.DataFrame(
    {'area': area,
     'date': date,
     'e1': e1,
     'e2': e2,
     'e3': e3   
    })
print(all_list )
#save as CSV file
all_list.to_csv('all.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense, I'll try this out.

Comment: thanks for accepting the answer, please keep us update , reading 7 million line would be some how challenging

Answer (score 1):

Simplest I can make it:

```
import pandas as pd

sample_lines = ['0010000413707312012026R','0010000413708212012027R','0010000413711062012029','0010004535307312012026D]']

COLUMN_NAMES = ['A','B','C','D','E']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=COLUMN_NAMES)
for line in sample_lines:
    row = [line[0:3], line[3:11], line[11:19], line[19:22], line[22:23]]
    df.loc[len(df)] = row

print (df)
```

Outputs:

```
     A         B         C    D  E
0  001  00004137  07312012  026  R
1  001  00004137  08212012  027  R
2  001  00004137  11062012  029   
3  001  00045353  07312012  026  D
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the file is too big, its better to read and save it into a different file, instead of read the entire file in memory:

```
with open('temp.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        code = line[0:3]
        registration = line[3:11]
        date = line[11:19]
        second_code = line[19:22]
        letter = line[22:]
        with open('modified.csv', 'a') as f2:
            f2.write(
                ' '.join([code, registration, date, second_code, letter]))
```

You can also read the content to from the txt file and use `extract` to divide the dataframe columns

```
df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv', header=None)
df

#       0
# 0 0010000413707312012026R
# 1 0010000413708212012027R
# 2 0010000413711062012029
# 3 0010004535307312012026D

df = df[df.columns[0]].str.extract('(.{3})(.{8})(.{8})(.{3})(.*)')
df
#   0   1           2           3   4
# 0 001 00004137    07312012    026 R
# 1 001 00004137    08212012    027 R
# 2 001 00004137    11062012    029 
# 3 001 00045353    07312012    026 D
```

Comment: I think OP is asking more about packing the result into `pandas` data frame, rather than writing it into new file